# How to get easy_install to upgrade into the correct directory?

Tags: linux, easy-install

If I run `easy_install -U distribute` it starts to upgrade using
`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.6.egg` but I need it to be in `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use --prefix=/usr to achieve this.

Apart from that it is usually not a good idea to modify the contents of /usr, which are normally maintained by the package management tools of your distribution. With python you can easily upgrade a package locally in your home directory by using --user. This will not confuse  the package management of your linux distribution but is specific to a certain user.